# What is the opus number of Charles Koechlin's Monody for English horn?

Tags: classical-music

Today, I heard

> Charles Koechlin's Monody for English horn
>
> Lajos Lencses
>
> CD CPO 999614-2

Does anyone know which opus number this work has?

Comment: Ahh, sorry @Shevliaskovic; I answered before I saw your comment.

Comment: @Richard it's okay. Even if the question is transferred, your answer will be transferred as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Amazon page for that CD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Y6VB) as well as a [collection of repertoire on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cor_anglais#Chamber_music) suggests it is Op. 216, No. 11.

Comment: The [French wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_œuvres_de_Charles_Koechlin) and the [cover image](http://bilder.buecher.de/zusatz/26/26011/26011800_deta_1.jpg) state op. 216 No. 11.

Comment: Oh, yikes; I had one job! Thanks, @guidot.